# Vue.js, using v-model to get information from v-for

Tags: node.js, vue.js, v-for, v-model

I have a dropdown box in a modal, that is populated with device objects.  I want to show the user only the `name` value of each device object.  It is doing this currently.  But when the user selects one of the device names, I want to use v-model to store the _id of the device selected, not the name.  I want this because the back end has to do a lot more work if I only have the name, instead of the _id.

Here is the template:

```
<template>
  <card-modal :visible="visible" @ok="buttonOK(selected)" @cancel="buttonCancel" :title="app.name" transition="zoom" :okText="'Add Device'">
    <div class="block">
      <p class="subtitle is-5">Choose a device to add to the app:</p>
      <select v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="device in devices">{{ device.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <span>Device: {{ selected }}</span>
    </div>
  </card-modal>
</template>
```

What is the best way for me to save the entire device object (or just the device._id) instead of just the device name, which is being selected by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `value` attribute of the `option` element to be the `_id` of each object:

```
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="device in devices" :value="device._id">{{ device.name }}</option>
  </select>
```

By assigning the value attribute, it will make the select element to have this value as the selected one.

See an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `<div>
  Selected: {{ selected }}
   <select v-model="selected">
      <option v-for="device in devices" :value="device._id">{{ device.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      selected: 1,
      devices: [
        { _id: 1, name: 'Device 1' },
        { _id: 2, name: 'Device 2' },
        { _id: 3, name: 'Device 3' },
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Very easy and helpful.  Thanks.  I didn't know about :value

Comment: @Brian, you're welcome. Note that the `value` attribute is just inherent to the [option element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). The colon (`:attribute`) syntax is a [shorthand](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands) to `v-bind:attribute`. It allows you to use objects and properties in the current context of the markup.